# Is it possible to use Immutable.Collections on C# Interactive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, read-eval-print-loop, immutable-collections

I am using the C# Interactive window (i.e. the REPL) on Visual Studio 2019, with latest updates. I want to use immutable collections but can't get them to work.  (I have no problem using them in a compiled C# project).

Strangely, if I enter (into C# Interactive window):

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
```

C# Interactive accepts this, implying that it can see the namespace. But if I then try to use it e.g.:

```
var a = ImmutableList.Create<int>(1,2,3);
```

I get the error message: 'The name 'ImmutableList' does not exist in the current context.'  It makes no difference if I fully-qualify the name of ImmutableList.

Possibly I am not understanding which version of .NET C# Interactive is working against.  I understand that Immutable.Collections are now native within .NET Core 3, but maybe C# Interactive doesn't use this version? (How can you tell/specify the .NET version in C# Interactive?).  Even so, it seems odd that it does not protest at the using directive.

Comment: What if you enter `using System.Collections.SomethingMadeUp;` does it accept that?

Comment: I'd already tried that. It immediately gives error 'The type or namespace name 'SomethingMadeUp' does not exist in ...'

Comment: Try adding a reference first with `#r "System.Collections.Immutable.dll"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the `System.Collections.Immutable` assembly first. To do that, use this:

```
#r "System.Collections.Immutable.dll"
```

Now you can use the object in the `System.Collections.Immutable` namespace.

Comment: Can you explain, though, why it will accept the using statement (when it rejects using SomethingMadeUp) even without that reference being added?

Comment: Not sure, I think there are some internal objects in that namespace. For example if you type `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray` it tells you *'ImmutableArray' is inaccessible due to its protection level*.

Comment: error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.Collections.Immutable.dll' could not be found